'noise value' in geometry nodes
I have this nodes setup in geometry nodes - using instance on points :

I got as expected :

but now , I want to generate 'noise' rather than 'random' but I can't find something like 'noise value'. Any solution ?
Here's what i'm looking for ( created in Houdini ) :


Instead of Random Value use a Noise Texture, there you can adjust the Scale of the noise. This generates values between 0 and 1 at the Fac output. Then you can use a Multiply math node or a Map Range etc. to adjust the min/max range of the values:

